# How to write a cell of strings to Excel in Matlab?

Tags: string, excel, matlab, cell

I am trying to write a short function that will take a cell of strings and will write it as is to Excel:

```
Excel = 

'r2g'    'r3g'    't2g'    't3b'    'c3b'    'r1r'    'r1g'    'r3r'    't3g'    't1r'
't1b'    't2b'    't3r'    'c1r'    't3g'    'r2b'    'r1g'    'c3b'    'c2b'    'c1b'
'c3r'    'c3g'    't2r'    'c1b'    'r1g'    'r1b'    'r3b'    'c1r'    't1r'    'r1r'
't3b'    'r2r'    't1r'    'r1r'    't3r'    't1g'    'r3r'    'r2g'    'c1r'    'r1g'
'c1g'    'r2g'    'r3r'    'r2b'    'c3r'    'c3b'    'c1b'    'r3g'    't1g'    't3r'
't1r'    'r2b'    'r3r'    't3g'    'r1g'    'c2g'    'r2g'    't1b'    'c1b'    'c1r'
'c3b'    't1r'    'r3b'    'r1r'    'r2r'    'c1b'    'c2g'    'c2b'    't1b'    'r2g'
'r2b'    'c3b'    't2g'    'c2r'    'c1b'    'c1g'    't3b'    'c2b'    'c3r'    't1r'
't3r'    't1r'    'r1r'    't2b'    'r3r'    'r1b'    't3b'    'c3g'    'c3b'    'r1g'
'r3b'    't2g'    'r2r'    'r1r'    't3b'    'c3b'    'c1r'    'r2g'    't1r'    'c2r'
```

I want each triplet to be in a different cell in Excel. I looked at the answers here regarding the strings array but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Have a look at your older questions... do 50% really have *no* acceptable answer? You should accept the best answer if it more or less solves your problem; otherwise people won't want to help you any more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the xlswrite function:

```
xlswrite('filename.xls', yourMatrix);
```

Edit: This function can accept either a matrix or a cell array. Thanks to commenters for pointing that out.

Comment: If you need to write cell array of strings you just pass it to `xlswrite`, it will work. Don't use `cell2mat`. You'd better to remove it from the answer.